# Identifying Inactive Contacts

Tags: contact, bestpractice

My question is not about how to deal with inactive contacts, but it is about how to identify inactive contacts.

Our Org has 300k Contacts, about 50%  of these are obsolete.

I have created a check box 'Active' but the challenge is to find a rule to identify which Contacts are truly 'Active'.

We have about 50 end users who deal with these contacts. Giving each one 3k contact to scrub through is an overkill.

If someone has dealt with similar situation, or has any ideas, can you please share?

Comment: *rule to identify which Contacts are truly 'Active'.* -- this has to be your Org specific as how you categorize an Active vs. Inactive Contact. There is no generic rule for this. You should look towards some data cleansing tools that should be able to scrub the data based on the rules you define if you don't want to do that manually.

Comment: Thanks @jayantDas for the response.

Answer (score 1):

user4947,
You could probably do this a few different ways.  If your end users are consistently logging calls and emails against these users, you could query out the most recent activity date, and go based on that.  If it's been 3 years since the last phone call or email with this Contact, then they are probably obsolete.  In that case, you use execute anonymous to extract a list of Contacts, and the most recently-created Task (email or call) on that Contact.

This query should work in Execute Anonymous, to preview the list:

```
system.debug([SELECT WhoId,MAX(CreatedDate) FROM Task WHERE WhoId != null GROUP BY WhoId]);
```

From there, you could basically go through each of the ContactIds, and if their most-recently created task is older than 3 years, set the Active checkbox to false.

Comment: Thanks @Aubry. I liked your suggestion. Our users do log call in Accounts, and relate the Contact who they need to speak to. I will try your suggestion.